# Get Privatekey for AWS SSL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

We are working on RedHat linux server with nodejs server.
While make my services ssl certified,
I got the SSL certificate from aws cli using ARN.
How could I get privatekey from aws ssl or how can I implement.

Comment: In the console, go to the IAM section, then Users, and select or create a user then in Security Credentials you can get a private key for them. So if you want to use one for your services you can create a user with the appropriate roles and get the key from there.

Comment: I was downloaded and used but at that time I got this error "x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch"

Comment: Are you using the ACM to generate the certificate? If so, you cannot get access to the private key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using AWS Certificate Mananager (ACM) to generate the key pair and issue SSL certificates, you do not have access to the private key. The private key is managed entirely within the service.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/kms.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes finally found the answer. while using load balancer for ssl certificate generation in AWS, we are no need to worry about ssl certificate things. the total things are handled by load balancer only.

what I did the wrong is, created load balancer for website in place classic load balancer for linux. Now it's working fine to me. No need to worry about ssl certificate while creating ssl certificate with load balancer in AWS

Thanks